# Issue with ha-proxy ACL matching

Tags: tcp, proxy, haproxy, amazon-elb, sni

First time trying out the AWS Network Load Balancer, with a pair of ha-proxy backend and having some issues that I cannot solve by myself. What I'm trying to do is using it a basic TCP proxy and this is my config so far:

```
frontend fe_https
  bind        *:443 tfo
  acl         myworld req_ssl_sni -i www.mysite.com
  capture     request header Host len 253
  capture     request header X-REQ-ID len 32
  capture     request header X-Unique-ID len 60
  mode        tcp
  option      tcplog
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  default_backend be_tarpit
  #use_backend be_https
  use_backend be_https if myworld

backend be_https
  description 'Backend for TCP proxy'
  mode        tcp
  option      tcplog
  option      tcp-check
  server      localdfw 127.0.0.1:8443 check send-proxy #verify none
```

But I get this on the browser:

```
This site can't provide a secure connection 
www.mysite.com sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

and this is in the log:

```
Nov 19 14:10:23 localhost haproxy[6634]: xx.xxx.xxx.118:40840 [19/Nov/2018:14:10:23.127] fe_https be_tarpit/<NOSRV> -1/-1/7 188 PR 0/0/0/0/3 0/0
```

The tarpit in the log shows that the ACL is not matching: it's not getting up to the *SERVER*, if ACL is enforced.

Does anyone know what am I missing? I have a similar setup and the only difference in there is a Classic ELB was used in stead of NLB.

Comment: Did you enable Proxy Protocol support on the NLB?  I'm not saying you should, but if you did, your HAProxy configuration is not expecting that, and the SNI test isn't going to work because the handshake will appear corrupted by the unexpected proxy preamble.  If you didn't, then that isn't the issue.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael-sqlbot!
I'm still getting my head around NLB - any idea how do I check if the Proxy Protocol enabled or not?

Comment: Check the target group settings.  It is not enabled by default.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html